# Implement zoom and reset functionality using action buttons in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

The given R script creates a tabPanel with four action buttons and a reactive scatterPlot from iris data. I want to enable functionality on other three buttons such that second button zooms in the plot, third button zooms-out and fourth button resets the selections done on the plot. I tried "zoom" package and zm() but not serving my purpose. Please help and thanks.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Zoom and Reset Dashboard",titleWidth = 290),
dashboardSidebar(
width = 0
),
dashboardBody(
# Creation of tabs and tabsetPanel
tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
tabPanel("Resource Dashboard", 

                  fluidRow(
                       column(1,
                            tags$head(
                                tags$style(HTML('#buttonresfreqone:hover {
                                                background-color: #008CBA;
                                                color: #ffffff;
                                                width: 150%;
                                                }'))
                                                   ),
                              tags$br(actionButton("buttonresfreqone", 
"Activity",style="color: #000000; width:100%;height:50px; ")),
                              tags$br(),
                              tags$head(
                                tags$style(HTML('#buttonresfreqtwo:hover {
                                                background-color: #008CBA;
                                                color: #ffffff;
                                                width: 150%;
                                                }'))
                                                   ),
                              tags$br(actionButton("buttonresfreqtwo", 
"Zoom-In",style="color: #000000; width:100%;height:50px; ")),
                              tags$br(),
                              tags$head(
                                tags$style(HTML('#buttonresfreqthree:hover {
                                                background-color: #008CBA;
                                                color: #ffffff;
                                                width: 150%;
                                                }'))
                                                   ),
                              tags$br(actionButton("buttonresfreqthree", 
"Zoom-Out",style="color: #000000; width:100%;height:50px; ")),
                              tags$br(),
                              tags$head(
                                tags$style(HTML('#buttonresfreqfour:hover {
                                                background-color: #008CBA;
                                                color: #ffffff;
                                                width: 150%;
                                                }'))
                                                   ),
                              tags$br(actionButton("buttonresfreqfour", 
HTML("Reset"),
                                                   style="color: #000000; 
width:100%;height:50px;"))),
                       tags$br(),
                       column(10,

                              box(title = "Resource Frequency", status = 
"primary",height = "460",width = "550", solidHeader = T,
                                  plotOutput("res_freq_plot"))))
                     ),
                     id= "tabselected"
            )

                                ))

server <- function(input, output) { 

#Code for Resource Dashboard Resource Frequency Plots

values_res_freq <- reactiveValues(res_freq_one = 0, res_freq_two = 0, 
res_freq_three = 0, 
                                res_freq_four = 0, res_freq_five = 0)
observeEvent(input$buttonresfreqone, {
values_res_freq$res_freq_one <- 1
values_res_freq$res_freq_two <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_three <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_four <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_five <- 0

})
observeEvent(input$buttonresfreqtwo, {
values_res_freq$res_freq_one <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_two <- 1
values_res_freq$res_freq_three <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_four <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_five <- 0

})
observeEvent(input$buttonresfreqthree, {
values_res_freq$res_freq_one <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_two <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_three <- 1
values_res_freq$res_freq_four <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_five <- 0

})
observeEvent(input$buttonresfreqfour, {
values_res_freq$res_freq_one <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_two <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_three <- 0
values_res_freq$res_freq_four <- 1
values_res_freq$res_freq_five <- 0
})
output$res_freq_plot <- renderPlot(
{

    if(values_res_freq$res_freq_one)
    plot(iris$Sepal.Length)
  else
    return()

}

)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Maybe you could do something like [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-zoom.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for replying, nice post but need this using action buttons only. Please help

Comment: By zooming do you mean zooming into particular area in the plot or increasing the size of the plot?

Comment: Clicking on zoom-in button, size of the plot should increase, clicking on zoom-out button, size should decrease, and clicking on reset button, I want to undo all selections.I have also added snapshot for your reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give the height and width to the renderPlot function as suggested in [this](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/650) link.

The first step would be creating reactive values for height and width with the default values, then altering the height and width value as per requirement of the clicked button.

I have modified your server code to do exactly that. Hope it helps!

```
server <- function(input, output) { 

  #Code for Resource Dashboard Resource Frequency Plots

  values_res_freq <- reactiveValues(res_freq_one = 0, res_freq_two = 0, 
                                    res_freq_three = 0, 
                                    res_freq_four = 0, res_freq_five = 0)

  #Reactive values for height and width of the plot
  Val <- reactiveValues(height = 400, width = 600)


  observeEvent(input$buttonresfreqone, {#Activity
    values_res_freq$res_freq_one <- 1
    values_res_freq$res_freq_two <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_three <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_four <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_five <- 0

  })
  observeEvent(input$buttonresfreqtwo, {#Zoom in
    values_res_freq$res_freq_one <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_two <- 1
    values_res_freq$res_freq_three <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_four <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_five <- 0

    #Increase height and width 
    Val$height <- Val$height *1.25
    Val$width <- Val$width *1.25

  })
  observeEvent(input$buttonresfreqthree, {#Zoom out
    values_res_freq$res_freq_one <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_two <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_three <- 1
    values_res_freq$res_freq_four <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_five <- 0

    #Decrease height and width 
    Val$height <- Val$height /1.25
    Val$width <- Val$width /1.25

  })
  observeEvent(input$buttonresfreqfour, {#Reset
    values_res_freq$res_freq_one <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_two <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_three <- 0
    values_res_freq$res_freq_four <- 1
    values_res_freq$res_freq_five <- 0

    #Set default value for height and width
    Val$height <- 400
    Val$width <- 600
  })

  observe({
    output$res_freq_plot <- renderPlot(
      {

        if(values_res_freq$res_freq_one)
          plot(iris$Sepal.Length)
        else
          return()

      }, height = Val$height, width = Val$width 

    )
  })


}
```

Comment: Awesome, it's working very nicely, just one slight issue, When I click on zoom-in button, it only zooms a blank screen, then I have to click on the activity button again to make the enhanced plot appear. similar case for zoom-out. I should click on the zoom function and entire plot should get enhanced. Thank you and please help.

Comment: That's because of the condition that you put `if(values_res_freq$res_freq_one)` in the `renderPlot` function. If you set  `values_res_freq$res_freq_one` to 1 instead of zero it should work.

Comment: Oh Thank you So So much, awsome help dear, great great help.

Comment: Hi SBista, regarding this discussion we had a little while back, I need one more help, your script helped me a lot,but I just want to implement a span functionality on the plot produced like clicking on the plot and moving it in any direction. If you can help me please with this. Thanks.

Comment: For panning you should consider using packages like `ggiraph`.

Comment: Sure, I'll check it, if you can provide me a good link with a working example, I can use it for reference, thanks.

Comment: You can check [this](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/221846_2ce0c17cc61740d7918ffa0c867ebf65.html) link.

Comment: Hmm, I see this is in accordance with the ggplot2 and plotly package. I know the span functionality that way. However, I just have a simple plot in R shiny by the command plot(iris$Sepal.Length). Just want to click on it and move. any easy way than that?

Comment: I guess you will need some amount of js code and won't be able to use simple `plotOutput` .You could try exploring the package `svgPanZoom`

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll check this package as per your suggestion and get back.